# Search input words from mysql database and sort on base of most related

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search

I want to get a result and sorted on the base of most related
.Here is a mysql table

```
id     sentence  
1      website download free idm here  
2      get a free idmas5 from here  
3      check out this idm  
4      Here is other softwares
```

Here is a code.

```
<?php
$word1 = 'download';
$word2 = 'idm';
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phrase WHERE MATCH(sentence)   
AGAINST('+$word1 +$word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE"))
//above query does not work
```

I want to get result from `MATCH.....AGAINST` and sort result like that.
Required Result.

```
1   website download free idm here  
3   check out this idm
2   get a free idmas5 from here
```

Because **download** and **idm** both are present in first id so it is on the top and in third id only **idm** is present it goes on second position.In second id the word 
**idmas5** is start from **idm** so it goes on thrd position.And in last id there is no word is matched so it can not displayed.

I am using `MATCH......AGAINST` I think it is good for that.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I am not able to get like these result.Please guide me how can I get like these result.Any idea

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a resultset on `SELECT`. so you need to assign the result like this

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phrase WHERE MATCH(sentence)   
AGAINST('+download +idm' IN BOOLEAN MODE"))
```

and then retrieve the result with function like `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    printf("ID: %s  SENTENCE: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```